# ASHX handler with ASP.NET MVC 3 and Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ashx

I would like to use [Silverlight Multi File Uploader](http://slfileupload.codeplex.com/releases/view/51136) with ASP.NET MVC 3. The problem is that I need to use ashx handler to handle file upload (the handler is part of the library). How can I integrate the handler with ASP.NET MVC 3 (I'm using Razor view engine) ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My guess is that it is easier because it is part of a (older?) third party library and it easier to just follow the instructions that tells you to set something in `web.config`. You should be able to ignore requests to `*.ashx` by ignoring routes to `*.ashx` files. You should be able to use something like this, but I haven't tried it myself:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you! All I needed to do was to add the ashx file to the root folder of the website and add the line mentioned above to the Global.asax and it works! :D

Comment: @kubal5003 How did you do that? What did the xml look like in the web.config?

Answer (score 9):

> The problem is that I need to use ashx handler to handle file upload

Who told you that you need a handler? Everything that you could do in a handler could be done in a controller action. You even have access to the raw `Request.InputStream` if necessary.

Comment: And even when your dealing with multiple file upload you could do a `ActionResult Upload(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)` + that multiple file upload is supported by HTML 5 `<input type="file" name="files" id="fileUpload" multiple="true" />`

Comment: @Major Byte, that will depend whether the Silverlight control sends a `multipart/form-data` encoded request. If it doesn't you will have to parse it manually.

Comment: Why should I write new code if there is something that I can reuse? This is the MUST you're looking for. I don't want to write custom action or result type or whatever. I want to reuse the existing code.

Comment: @kubal5003, if you want to reuse the existing code, what integration do you need with your current application? Personally I would readapt it. Using raw http handlers in an ASP.NET MVC application where you have controller actions is against good practices. Depending on your requirements and what exactly you are trying to achieve it will be more or less difficult to use the handler as is.

Comment: I agree that creating custom controller would normally be the preferred way, but I just have no time to deal with that right now. The solution with raw handler works well and is probably a little faster because ASP.NET MVC is a handler itself (the difference is probably negligible and it's not my goal)

Comment: Streaming MP4 with segment requests is not easy in MVC Result from controller. Using a generic handler you have more leverage over the response/request with less overhead. Especially if serving video to multiple places.