# Define ashx file in MVC doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I define a **ashx** file in MVC4 project in **content** folder so it doesn't work ?!!

So i have several questions?

1- Can we define **ashx** file in MVC or it isn't possible?

2-If we can define  how can we do that?

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use an .ashx file in MVC. An MVC app is an ASP.NET Web app. You should add the .ashx in the root folder (not the content folder), or in a normal subfolder, as you would in an ordinary ASP.NET web project.

Comment: Thank you .So i read some post that  i should add this to global file :routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289036/ashx-handler-with-asp-net-mvc-3-and-razor

Comment: When i changed the location of my ashx file to a folder in the root it works thank you .so why ?